# Does one need defensive copies for Java enum types?

Tags: java, enums, immutability

One should return so-called "defensive copies" of private reference types. That's to avoid returning the reference of a private field.

I would like to know if that's necessary for private enum types. I read somewhere that enums are immutable reference types, so the answer should be 'no'. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the answer is `no`.

Comment: @kocko: No, they're not immutable necessarily. It's up to the implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enums aren't *inherently* immutable - but you wouldn't be able to create a defensive copy anyway, as there's only a fixed set of instances available - you'd *have* to return a reference to one of the existing instances, rather than creating a new instance.

Enums generally *should* be immutable anyway, but to counteract the claims that they inherently *are* immutable:

```
enum BadEnum {
    INSTANCE;

    private int foo;

    private int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public int setFoo(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BadEnum.INSTANCE.setFoo(10);
        System.out.println(BadEnum.INSTANCE.getFoo()); // Prints 10
    }
}
```

So in short:

- Make your enums immutable. I can't remember ever even *wanting* to create a mutable enum.
- You can't and shouldn't try to make defensive copies.

Comment: Mmmmmm, enums with mutable fields... When I'll be a super villain, I'll do code with those, and let my minions suffer by having them maintain the code... But I'll have to practice evil laugh quite a bit until then, so back to the real world...

Comment: Can you suggest some resources for ensuring Enums are immutable? I had assumed it was the same as the pattern for designing classes as immutable, but I'm not sure and can't find much material.

Comment: @NathanChristie: Yes, it is. Make all the variables final, and make sure they're immutable types themselves (e.g. `String` and `int`, but not `Date` or `Calendar`). If you *do* have to use a mutable type, make sure you never return the reference directly - just make a defensive copy.